# how to change NFS share name as displayed in OSX without reconfiguring NFS server?

Tags: macos, filesystem, nfs

I am mounting an NFS share named "storage" from my-host-**here1**.com. I also want to mount another NFS share named "storage" from my-host-**here2**.com.

I just want to know how can I change the share name as shown in Finder so it's easier for me to know which is which.

e.g.

"storage" from my-host-here1.com will be displayed as storage-here1
"stoarge" from my-host-here2.com will be displayed as storage-here2.

**I set the auto-mounting by dragging the NFS share icon in my desktop to the login items in System Preferences.**

I did search the net before creating this topic but not getting any luck.

Thanks very much :)

update: I am able to manually specify a share name when mounting via /etc/auto_master. BUT the share does not show in finder like shares (samba or NFS) made via Finder -> Connect to Server.

Answer (score 2):

This is *not* possible, as far as I can tell. The answer from patrix will indeed mount the share at a different mount point (though you need to create the mount point), but no matter where you mount it, Finder will still show it by the 'Proper' name.

You can verify by doing Get Info on the mounted drive in /Volumes/; the "Name & Extension" section will show the custom name you specified, but the name at the top of the window (and in the Finder) will be the actual name of the share's final path component.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the local name when calling `mount`:

```
mount -t nfs my-host-here1.com:/storage /Volumes/storage-here1
mount -t nfs my-host-here2.com:/storage /Volumes/storage-here2
```

Comment: I set the auto-mounting by dragging the NFS share icon in my desktop to the login items in System Preferences

Comment: I've done what you suggested **before** creating the topic but I want it to auto-mount with my custom share name :)